# Control start up manager

Tags: winapi

I would like to know is there anyway to identify that my app is executed manually or in  window start up..I will explain why I need this
My application  made as start up application which creates system tray icon.whenever user launch my app it creates system tray and shows a dialog box..but in start up I should not show dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter when you run it as startup, like `/startup` and check for it at runtime.